# Administrar Wordpress desde otra instalación

Tags: wordpress

Tengo un cliente con un sitio de alto tráfico. El portal está desarrollado con Wordpress y está teniendo problemas últimamente.

Pasa que por la buena caché que tiene el portal, el front nunca tiene fallas de conexión. Pero en el administrador del mismo si tiene este problema y mantiene caído.

Yo he estado pensando en esta solución: Administrar el sitio desde otro administrador.

Es decir: 
sitioweb.com (Donde todos ven el contenido)
adminsitioweb.com donde los periodistas suben el contenido.

Alguien lo ha realizado? O alguna idea que compartir para yo hacer esta actividad?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si admin sitio web esta en el mismo servidor, vas a tener el mismo problema. No sera el problema con algun plugin que trabe el acceso correcto al administrador?

Answer (score 0):

En vez de otra instalación de WP yo me iría por un dashboard personalizado para los periodistas desde donde puedan gestionar sus perfiles y publicar en el sitio..

Esto se hace con el API de WordPress que te permite acceder al contenido del mismo desde el exterior... de esta forma podrías poner laravel dentro de tu WP y te quedaría por ejemplo así: **[www.tusitio.com/paneldecontrol](http://www.tusitio.com/paneldecontrol)** o algo así..